# Scala language relates in some way with ScalaScript

Tags: scala, programming-languages, scala-script

My boss ia bashing Scala language due to an previous experience with ScalaScript from https://scala.com so are there some relationship between they?

I am trying to evagelize Scala in my company, so it is important to eliminate this misunderstandings.

Comment: Is that a scala.js ?? or something different?

Comment: What research did you do? What did you find? What is still unclear? You'll get better answers for more specific questions, rather than a "do my work for me" question.

Comment: @Robert, I didn't find any relevant result on searches that i made, so I hope that someone in scala community could help to clear up this kind of misunderstanding so that others can find this answer in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Scala.com is the home of Scala, Inc. a producer of multimedia software. It was founded in 1987 as a Norwegian company called Digital Visjon. They work with digital signage solutions (commercial or enterprise digital media displays and related scripts and communication, etc.)

They have absolutely no connection whatsoever to the [scala language](https://www.scala-lang.org/).

Comment: I asked a Scala rep once why they called their product "Scala" (to be fair, that's now the company name, though it used to be the name of the software, too, and it ends up being a common shorthand name for either). Their answer: because they've been around longer. And it's true. The programming language (scala-lang.org) was founded in 2004. The digital signage company has been around since 1987 and has been named Scala since 1990.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe scala.com is related to Scala the language: maybe they use the language internally, maybe their "solutions" are somehow based on the Scala language, who knows ... My hunch is that they are not related, because it they were they would advertise it or change name.

However, Scala the language is definitely not related to scala.com. I had never heard of this thing before.